# ReactiveSwift mutable property with read only public access

Tags: swift, reactive-swift

I have a class with enum property `state`. This property's value (by value I mean `ReactiveSwift.Property`'s value) needs to be accessed and observed by other classes, but value change should be private. Currently it is implemented in a such way:

```
enum State {
    case stopped, running, paused
}

var state: Property<State> {
    return Property(mutableState)
}
fileprivate let mutableState = MutableProperty<State>(.stopped)
```

This pattern allows me to modify `mutableState` property within class file. At the same time outside the class state is available only for reading and observing.

The question is whether there is a way to implement a similar thing using single property? Also probably someone can suggest a better pattern for the same solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't think of any way to do this with a single property. The only adjustment I would make to your code is to make `state` a stored property rather than a computed property that gets newly created each time it is accessed:

```
class Foo {
    let state: Property<State>

    fileprivate let mutableState = MutableProperty<State>(.stopped)

    init() {
        state = Property(mutableState)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but probably making it lazy would be even a better solution. But your definitely makes sense as well.

Answer (score 1):

Depending where you want to mutate the state, you can try doing either of:

```
private(set) var state: Property<State>
```

or if you modify it from an extension but still the same file

```
fileprivate(set) var state: Property<State>
```

Comment: yeah, I thought about this. But this allows me to modify `state` property by itself. And I need to modify the value of `state` property. I mean `ReactiveSwift.Property` as well as `ReactiveSwift.MutableProperty` has property `value`. That's the one I need to modify. Sorry for confusion.